# Layout manager for HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, layout, canvas, kineticjs

I am working on a project to animate the Data Structures on HTML5 Canvas. I am currently using KineticJs and have looked into other canvas related libraries too. But I have failed to find  Layout Manager of any sort in them. Right now if I have to put some rectangles and circles etc. I have to specify their exact coordinates. What I want is something like FlowLayout Manager or Grid layout manager in which if I put some objects they don't overlap on each other and I don't need to mention each of their exact coordinates. When I add new shapes to it they automatically adjust their location accordingly.

Is there any library which provides such feature or What can be the best way to do it ? I am relatively new to the client side programming and HTML5 so if it is very basic please point me right direction to study further.

Comment: Why not just use something displayed as a table?

Comment: In a way the canvas itself is a table right. I have mention the position of each objects in it. But what I want is that I just push lets say 20 circles and 10 rectangles into the canvas and layout just put them one after the other so that they don't overlap without me mentioning their exact coordinates.

Comment: With the canvas element you would need to manage the circles and rectangles yourself (even with kineticjs). You would be better off with a table, inserting canvas' into this table and drawing what you want.